Make caption's left-justified margin relative to itemize item's leftmargin?
Given the minimal example below, the Listing 1 is correct in that it's left-justified and lines up with the indented listing.
However, when a listing is inside an itemize item, even though the listing itself is correct in that it's indented more, the Listing 2 is not additionally indented to match.
I assume this happens because the margin=\lstleftmargin inside captionsetup is absolute. But how do I make the caption relative the current item's leftmargin (if any) so that it always lines up with the listing above it?
Note: whatever change(s) need to be made also need to work when I use \lstinputlisting to include longer listings from a separate file.
\def \lstleftmargin{.4in}   % global for listing left margin

\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{
  format=hang,
  justification=raggedright,
  margin=\lstleftmargin,
  singlelinecheck=false
}

\usepackage{courier}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{parsep=0pt}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  abovecaptionskip=\medskipamount,
  aboveskip=\baselineskip,
  belowcaptionskip=0pt,
  belowskip=\baselineskip,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos=b,
  keepspaces=true,
  keywordstyle=\lst@ifdisplaystyle\bfseries\fi\normalsize,
  morekeywords={constexpr},
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  tabsize=2,
  xleftmargin=\lstleftmargin
}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={\lstinline|swapi|, version 1}]
void swapi( int *pa, int *pb ) {
  int temp = *pa;
  *pa = *pb;
  *pb = temp;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{itemize}
\item
\lipsum[2][1]
\begin{lstlisting}
constexpr size_t BUF_SIZE   = 4096;
constexpr char   GREETING[] = "hello, world";
\end{lstlisting}

\item
\lipsum[2][2]

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={\lstinline|swapi|, version 2, with \lstinline|const|}, label=lst:swapi-v3]
void swapi( int *pa, int *pb ) {  // swap int, v3 --- with const
  const int temp = *pa;           // specify temp won't change
  *pa = *pb;
  *pb = temp;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}


Do you really want to use \lstleftmargin as left and right margin of captions? In the follow example, I use instead only a left margin. Additional I would recommend not to use \def in a LaTeX document, but either \newcommand or — in case of a length — \newlength.
Now to change the left margin of the caption depending on the list environment, you can use package enumitem. The package provides option first* for lists, to add code, that is executed at the very beginning of the list:
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newlength{\lstleftmargin}
\setlength{\lstleftmargin}{.4in}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{
  format=hang,
  justification=raggedright,
  margin={\lstleftmargin,0pt},% use \lstleftmargin for the left margin only
  singlelinecheck=false
}

\usepackage{courier}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{parsep=0pt}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  abovecaptionskip=\medskipamount,
  aboveskip=\baselineskip,
  belowcaptionskip=0pt,
  belowskip=\baselineskip,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos=b,
  keepspaces=true,
  keywordstyle=\lst@ifdisplaystyle\bfseries\fi\normalsize,
  morekeywords={constexpr},
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  tabsize=2,
  xleftmargin=\lstleftmargin
}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter% makes not sense, if there wasn't a \frontmatter before

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={\lstinline|swapi|, version 1}]
void swapi( int *pa, int *pb ) {
  int temp = *pa;
  *pa = *pb;
  *pb = temp;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{itemize}[first*={\captionsetup[lstlisting]{margin={\dimeval{\leftmargin+\lstleftmargin},0pt}}}]
\item
\lipsum[2][1]
\begin{lstlisting}
constexpr size_t BUF_SIZE   = 4096;
constexpr char   GREETING[] = "hello, world";
\end{lstlisting}

\item
\lipsum[2][2]

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={\lstinline|swapi|, version 2, with \lstinline|const|}, label=lst:swapi-v3]
void swapi( int *pa, int *pb ) {  // swap int, v3 --- with const
  const int temp = *pa;           // specify temp won't change
  *pa = *pb;
  *pb = temp;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}


You could also use \setlist to define the indent globally, but this would also affect to floating listings, which is IMHO not a good idea.
It would also be possible to use another caption format inside lists:
\documentclass[10pt]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newlength{\lstleftmargin}
\setlength{\lstleftmargin}{.4in}
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption}
\makeatletter
\DeclareCaptionFormat{list}{\@hangfrom{\hspace\leftmargin#1#2}#3}
\makeatother
\captionsetup[lstlisting]{
  format=hang,
  justification=raggedright,
  margin={\lstleftmargin,0pt},% use \lstleftmargin for the left margin only
  singlelinecheck=false
}

\usepackage{courier}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{parsep=0pt,first=\captionsetup[lstlisting]{format=list}}% CAVEAT:
                                % This global change would also change the
                                % caption of listings with option float.

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{letterpaper}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{
  language=C,
  abovecaptionskip=\medskipamount,
  aboveskip=\baselineskip,
  belowcaptionskip=0pt,
  belowskip=\baselineskip,
  basicstyle=\small\ttfamily,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
  breaklines=true,
  captionpos=b,
  keepspaces=true,
  keywordstyle=\lst@ifdisplaystyle\bfseries\fi\normalsize,
  morekeywords={constexpr},
  showspaces=false,
  showstringspaces=false,
  showtabs=false,
  tabsize=2,
  xleftmargin=\lstleftmargin
}

\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}
\mainmatter% makes not sense, if there wasn't a \frontmatter before

\lipsum[1][1-3]

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={\lstinline|swapi|, version 1}]
void swapi( int *pa, int *pb ) {
  int temp = *pa;
  *pa = *pb;
  *pb = temp;
}
\end{lstlisting}

\begin{itemize}
\item
\lipsum[2][1]
\begin{lstlisting}
constexpr size_t BUF_SIZE   = 4096;
constexpr char   GREETING[] = "hello, world";
\end{lstlisting}

\item
\lipsum[2][2]

\begin{lstlisting}[caption={\lstinline|swapi|, version 2, with
    \lstinline|const| and some more text to show how the paragraph break
    inside captions work}, label=lst:swapi-v3]
void swapi( int *pa, int *pb ) {  // swap int, v3 --- with const
  const int temp = *pa;           // specify temp won't change
  *pa = *pb;
  *pb = temp;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{itemize}

\end{document}



I used margin with the ,0pt also, but then some Listing were not indented at all. It took me a while to figure out that I also need oneside. I'd rather not have to specify the first stuff on every itemize that just so happens to have a listing in it. Setting it globally seems to work fine.
